# Hidden_field tag grabbing an id from a form select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code where I want to take the selected photo (from a drop-down) and pass it into a `hidden_field`. The collection select is a group of photos and I am using the same variable `@photos` within the `hidden_field`.

```
<%= f.select :photo_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@photos, :id, :name), {include_blank: "- Select A Photo-"} %>
<%= f.hidden_field(:photo_id, value: @photos.id)%>
```

I realize that using the variable that holds all the photos in the hidden field is incorrect because I don't want to all the photo's id's... but how might I get that one selected photo id?

I tried looking at some Rails sources and started running circles as I quickly confused myself... If you happen to know of a good source for this I would greatly appreciate a link as well.

Comment: Why do you need hidden field for? the first select statement will get you the id of the selected photo:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag

Answer (score 0):

Forms are like hashes in that they can only have one value per key. So if you have two input fields that both have a `name="photo[photo_id]"` then the latter one will prevail.

I think what you want to do is have the `hidden_field` be the carrier of the value, but the select field be the chooser of the value. I can't think of a way to do this except with javascript.

```
<%= f.select_tag :photo_id...
<%= f.hidden_field :photo_id, value: current_selected_photo.id...
```

And then in javascript (coffeescript):

```
$ ->
  $('select[name="photo_id"]').on 'change', ->
    $('input[name="photo[photo_id]"').val($(@).val())
```